# How can I delete whitespace backwards until end of previous word?

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode

I want to delete whitespace backwards until end of previous word.

Say, I have the cursor on the character "d" in the word "dog":

`horse cat           dog`

If I press `Ctrl-W` (Insert mode) or `db` (Normal mode), then "cat" is deleted, which I don't want.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27255/how-can-i-make-a-single-mapping-take-effect-for-both-normal-mode-insert-mode-a#comment49033_27255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal mode:

```
cTt
```

Then press space

Comment: This only works when the previous word ends in "t".

Answer (score 3):

How about `hdiw`?  I.e. move into the space and then delete the "word" formed by the whitespace.  That will give you:

```
horse catdog
```

To keep 1 space between `cat` and `dog`, the best I can think of is `ge2ldw`, i.e. go to the end of the previous word, move to the second space in the gap, and delete to the start of the next word.

Answer (score 2):

Using Vim's jump to first letter in line can be useful in situations like this.

```
dTt
```

delete backwards until you reach letter t, but dont include letter itself.